# Standard/common Windows controls bitmap resources

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, resources, shared-libraries

I was wondering if there are any bitmap resources for Windows controls stored in some library?

My original idea was to find everything nicely at one place: for instance, everything that relates to the "classical" standard controls in one library (radio button's circular symbols [selected/unselected], checkbox button's square symbol [checked/unchecked/3rd state], etc.). But so far, I managed to find merely bitmaps related to the standard checkbox button, namely resource id 2365 (0x93D) in Comres.dll (with duplicities contained in a ton of other libraries). Unfortunately enough, I yet didn't manage to find anything else, like for instance the above mentioned states of a radio button, or the "plus" sign of an expanded/collapsed item in a tree view (the "[+]" and "[-]" signs that appear next to each folder in Windows Explorer, for instance), etc.

I believe such resources must exist somewhere, yet haven't found where.

Comment: The theme API exposes facilities to let you draw these things to a device

Comment: There is no "once place", several of the items you mention are not resources but simply painted.  You can't use them anyway, protected by copyright.  Microsoft does make a lot of images and icons available that you can use in your own app, Google "visual studio image library".  Don't expect miracles.